# Conflict with finite Moufang loop solvability propositions

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups, solvable-groups, quasigroups

I really got stuck with the following contradiction.
Say we have a [Moufang loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moufang_loop) $Q$, $|Q| < \infty$.
To put it briefly, Moufang loops are groups that not necessary be associative, with extra identities. They are also quasigroups with neutral element.

1. The classical [loop solvability](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.05733.pdf) is equal to existence for loop $Q$ series $1 = A_0 \triangleleft A_1 \triangleleft\space ... \triangleleft\space A_n = Q$, $A_{i+1} / A_i$ - commutative group;
2. There is a [Feit-Thompson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_theorem) which say that every finite group with odd order is solvable. In [this work](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869368900501) the theorem is proved for finite Moufang loops;
3. Simple Moufang loop is a loop without nontrivial proper [normal subloops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normal_subloop). Finite simple nonassociative Moufang loops are called [Paige loops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Paige_loop);
4. There is a [nice representation of Paige loops](http://www.cs.du.edu/~petr/data/papers/finite_simple_Moufang_loops.pdf) as a 3-generated loops. For Paige loops with odd order $q \neq 9$ the generators can be the following:

   $\begin{pmatrix}1 & (1,0,0)\\\ (0,0,0) & 1\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}1 & (0,1,0)\\\ (0,0,0) & 1\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}0 & (0,0,u)\\\ (0,0,u^{-1}) & 1\end{pmatrix}$, where

   $u$ - primitive element of [$GF(q)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) (with $q$ elements);
5. Trivial check on commutativity of second and third generators by rule

   $\begin{pmatrix}a & \alpha\\\ \beta & b\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}c & \gamma\\\ \delta & d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}ac+\alpha\delta & a\gamma+d\alpha-\beta\times\delta\\ c\beta+b\delta+\alpha\times\gamma & bd+\beta\gamma\end{pmatrix}$

   Gives us that Paige loops are always noncommutative (generally regardless to the parity);
6. Finally, by definition of solvability
   $Q$ - simple finite solvable loop $\Rightarrow$ $Q$ - commutative (quotient of $Q$ by $1$).
   Particularly by Feit-Thompson theorem, Paige loops with odd order are solvable, hence since they are simple, they must be commutative, but we showed that Paige loops are never commutative. **A contradiction**.

My question is: where the misfire is? What tricky moment I couldn't see here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Paige_loop,
the order of a Paige loop is $q^3(q^4-1)$ when $q$ is even and $\frac{1}{2}q^3(q^4-1)$ when $q$ is odd. Hence a Paige loop can never have odd order.

Comment: Yes, this night I realized it, too :)